# Angular - How to delete dynamic component without reference to hostView

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a draggable popup window in Angular that can be created dynamically using *ComponentFactory*. It was working well until I created a table component that 'inherits' from the draggable component so I can inject html into it using `<ng-content>`

There's quite a lot of code so here is the link to the Github Repo for this project.
https://github.com/Stevenjohnlally/Angular-Dynamic-Popups

I will try my best to explain my thought process here.

In the **AppComponent** there is a `<div #popupContainer></div>` which is the *ViewContainerRef* so I can create the dynamic popups and insert them there.

I have a **PopupManagerService** which allows me to open new popups from any other component. A component can call the `openPopup()` function then the service will emit an event to the **AppComponent** to tell it to create a new popup.

The way I keep track of each new popup is by storing its own *hostView* in its own instance. So that when a popup wants to delete itself it can pass its *hostView* to the **PopupManagerService** and it can easily find it.

This works all fine until except for the **TableComponent**. It is basically a component that attaches a table to the *popup-content* of the **DragDropDialogComponent**.

Basically, now I just want to find a way to close the **TableComponent** the same way the **DragDropDialogComponent** closes.